# select * from in php (PDO) but I cant see my echo?

Tags: php, pdo

I´m trying to do the right thing in PHP, and use PDO.

I have a table, where I need to echo data.

So I use,

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM under_a');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//use $results?>
```

but in my table, where i use

```
<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?>
```

I don't get anything, so what is wrong?

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM under_a, studie');
//$row = $stmt->execute();

//$results = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//use 

while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
var_dump($row); 
} 
?>


<table width="1100" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bold_font">
<tr>
<td width="75" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?></td>
<td width="50" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Lys</td>
<td width="50" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Skilt</td>
```

Comment: execute `print_r($row);` in order to see if there is something in that array

Comment: Do you use `<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?>` inside foreach?

Comment: You haven't declared `$row` anywhere, did you?!

Comment: use this.
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}

Answer (score 1):

you have loop through the result array like this

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row['etDate'];
}
```

***UPDATE***

i didn't understand your need mate, i hope this helps

```
<?php

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM under_a,studie');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


foreach ($results as $row) 

{

?>
<table width="1100" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bold_font">
<tr>
<td width="75" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?></td>
<td width="50" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Lys</td>
<td width="50" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Skilt</td>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: but my echo is in a table

<td width="75" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?></td>

Comment: no problem,try this 
echo '<td width="75" height="25" class="info">' .$row["etDate"].'</td>'

Comment: but my tabel is out side my php, look at my last code

Comment: hmmmm do I have to put my tabel inside my php code now

Comment: can you tell me how you want the output will be?do you want to show all the values in $row['etdate'] or a single row?

Comment: just one single row, I have others rows, that is going into the table as well. And when I enter somee new info in my db, it will make a new table with my new info

Comment: see my updated answer,i think that is what you are asking for :|

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: and this is what I´m trying to do
http://overskov-hansen.dk/Brand.php

This one is old style mysql connect

Comment: hello? no ide what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

you have need to change your code.

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM under_a');
$page = $stmt->execute();

$results = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//use $results?>

while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 var_dump($row); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` to print `etDate`

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    print $row['etDate'];
}
```

Comment: when I use while I get some info

    array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["post_id"]=> string(2) "17" ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["lys"]=> string(2) "OK" ["skilt"]=> string(2) "OK" ["door"]=> string(2) "OK" ["etDate"]=> string(10) "17.02.2014" } } 

But still no echo where I want it

Comment: @user3272367 you are getting array, now use `foreach` to print `etDate`

Comment: Where do you want it to echo ?

Comment: I want to echo in my tabel